# Dynamicaly add event to Meteor template

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, pug

In my Meteor.JS app I want to dynamicaly add click events on elements taken from database. Unfortunately, function is not triggered after click (but event is added to Template.algorithms.__eventsMap property). I am wondering if my approach is right and what can be corrected to make that event trigger.

main.coffee:

```
Template.algorithms.onCreated ->
  Template.instance().subscribe('algorithm-descriptions', {
    onReady: () ->
      for alg in AlgorithmDescriptions.find().fetch()
        Template.algorithms.events({
          "click .#{alg.button}": () ->
            $(".#{alg.divClass}").scrollintoview({duration: 'slow'})
    })
})
```

algorithms.jade:

```
.col-md-2
  ul
    each alg in algorithmDescriptions
      li(class=alg.button)=alg.name
.col-md-10
  each alg in algorithmDescriptions
    div(class=alg.div)
      h2=alg.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is incorrect.

Solution:

While looping through 'each' in the template, attach a class (e.g. `'clickHere'`) and give the `id` of the document to it.

Example

template.html - (Sorry!, I never used jade)

```
   {{#each alg}}
            <div class="clickHere" id="{{id}}">
                 h2={{name}}
             </div>
        {{/each}}
```

template.js (Sorry!, I also never used coffeescript)

```
Template.algorithms.events({
     "click .clickHere" : function(){
         var id=this._id;
        $("#"+id).scrollintoview({duration: 'slow'})
     }
});
```

Please convert the scripts to jade and coffee and this should work.